# 5 Column background DIV to fill empty space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need all of my columns on a page to appear be the same height. I'd be fine doing this if there were just one background colour but there are 5, taking up 20% of the width each on a desktop.

```css
.container {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #91F5AD 20%, #8FBFE0 20%, #7C77B9 20%, #0BC9CD 20%, #05A8AA 20%);
}

.col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #91F5AD;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col1{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #91F5AD;
}
}

.col2 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #8FBFE0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col2{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #8FBFE0;
}
}

.col3 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #7C77B9;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col3{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #7C77B9;
}
}

.col4 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #0BC9CD;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col4{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0BC9CD;
}
}

.col5 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #05A8AA;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col5{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #05A8AA;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="col1"><br></div>
<div class="col2"><br></div>
<div class="col3"><br></div>
<div class="col4"><br></div>
<div class="col5"><br></div>
</div>
```

I need the container to replicate the pattern of the DIV backgrounds in order to make it seem as though they're all the same height.

If you see below, you'll see the issue.

```css
    .container {
        display: table;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(to right,  #91F5AD 20%, #8FBFE0 20%, #7C77B9 20%, #0BC9CD 20%, #05A8AA 20%);
    }

    .col1 {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #91F5AD;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col1{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #91F5AD;
    }
    }

    .col2 {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #8FBFE0;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col2{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #8FBFE0;
    }
    }

    .col3 {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #7C77B9;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col3{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #7C77B9;
    }
    }

    .col4 {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #0BC9CD;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col4{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #0BC9CD;
    }
    }

    .col5 {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #05A8AA;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col5{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #05A8AA;
    }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="col1"><br></div>
<div class="col2"><br></div>
<div class="col3"><br></div>
<div class="col4"><br></div>
<div class="col5"><br></div>
<br><br>
</div>
<p>The green is fine but the rest don't match above themselves</p>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: height 100% with overflow? that work?

Comment: Are you going to mark the answer that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Make the display of the children divs `table-cell` since you have the parent's display as `table`, and remove the floats:

```
.container > div {
display:table-cell;
}
```

Example:

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #91F5AD 20%, #8FBFE0 20%, #7C77B9 20%, #0BC9CD 20%, #05A8AA 20%);
}

.col1 {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #91F5AD;
}

.container>div {
  display: table-cell;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .col1 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #91F5AD;
  }
}

.col2 {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #8FBFE0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .col2 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #8FBFE0;
  }
}

.col3 {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #7C77B9;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .col3 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #7C77B9;
  }
}

.col4 {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #0BC9CD;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .col4 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0BC9CD;
  }
}

.col5 {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #05A8AA;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .col5 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #05A8AA;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1"><br></div>
  <div class="col2"><br></div>
  <div class="col3"><br></div>
  <div class="col4"><br></div>
  <div class="col5"><br></div>
  <br><br>
</div>
<p>The green is fine but the rest don't match above themselves</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get you what you exactly trying to achieve , but as far as I understood you need gradient background for all of your col. , I think in bootstrap you can easily achieve that by setting background gradient - col-12 and then drop your col. Like col-3, col-3 ....

Comment: Could you please try and fix the error within `background: linear-gradient(to right,  #91F5AD 20%, #8FBFE0 20%, #7C77B9 20%, #0BC9CD 20%, #05A8AA 20%);`

Answer (score 0):

Make your children divs `position:relative` then apply a height of 100% on them. Note: Also add `&nbsp;` inside them (if you have no other content to put into them) so the height css property takes.

```css
  .container {
        display: table;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(to right,  #91F5AD 20%, #8FBFE0 20%, #7C77B9 20%, #0BC9CD 20%, #05A8AA 20%);
    }

    .col1 {
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #91F5AD;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col1{
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #91F5AD;
    }
    }

    .col2 {
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #8FBFE0;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col2{
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #8FBFE0;
    }
    }

    .col3 {
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #7C77B9;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col3{
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #7C77B9;
    }
    }

    .col4 {
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #0BC9CD;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col4{
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #0BC9CD;
    }
    }

    .col5 {
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #05A8AA;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col5{
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #05A8AA;
    }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="col1"><br>
&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col2"><br>
&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col3"><br>
&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col4"><br>
&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col5"><br>
&nbsp;</div>
<br><br>
</div>
<p>The green is fine but the rest don't match above themselves</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of css stuff that makes me wonder if my submission will be sufficient, but:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px; // or whatever
}

.container div {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: red; //or whatever
}

.col2 {
  background-color: orange; //or whatever
}

.col3 {
  background-color: yellow; //or whatever
}

.col4 {
  background-color: blue; //or whatever
}

.col5 {
  background-color: indigo; //or whatever
}

.container .content {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="col1"><br></div>
<div class="col2"><br></div>
<div class="col3"><br></div>
<div class="col4"><br></div>
<div class="col5"><br></div>
<div class="content">Put whatever you want here, including other elements</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's close to working with `flex`, my only issue now is that content can't be added below those columns.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. Do you want content in the columns? Content sorted as the columns are sorted, but not colored? A line of content beneath the columns?

Comment: The DIVs are ` | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |` and the container is `|    12345    |`, I want it so that the container follows the same colour pattern as the DIVs, the only line in the CSS with the issue is `background: linear-gradient(to right,  #91F5AD 20%, #8FBFE0 20%, #7C77B9 20%, #0BC9CD 20%, #05A8AA 20%);`

Comment: I don't know your full use case, but I would recommend giving each column a color and avoiding the gradient entirely.

Comment: That's what I've done. If I then set the container to flex how do I then place content below it.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I've updated the snippet to demo to do that. Let me know if that works.

It's a lot, but there's a really great flex reference at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You did not properly set your gradient in the first place.

you need to set the start and stop value for the colors, you did set all of them at 20%.

it should more like : **`background: linear-gradient(to right,  #91F5AD 20%, #8FBFE0 20%, #8FBFE0 40%, #7C77B9 40%,#7C77B9 60%, #0BC9CD 60%,  #0BC9CD 80%, #05A8AA 80%);`** *(0% and 100% do not need to be written since it is not mixing with another color)*

infos here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient .

See snippet below

```css
.container {
        float: left;/* or display:table is fine to deal with floatting child , both is not necessary */
        width: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(to right,  #91F5AD 20%, #8FBFE0 20%, #8FBFE0 40%, #7C77B9 40%,#7C77B9 60%, #0BC9CD 60%,  #0BC9CD 80%, #05A8AA 80%);
    }

    .col1 {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #91F5AD;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col1{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #91F5AD;
    }
    }

    .col2 {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #8FBFE0;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col2{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #8FBFE0;
    }
    }

    .col3 {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #7C77B9;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col3{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #7C77B9;
    }
    }

    .col4 {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #0BC9CD;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col4{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #0BC9CD;
    }
    }

    .col5 {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #05A8AA;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .col5{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #05A8AA;
    }
    }
    .container>div {background:none!important;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="col1"><br></div>
<div class="col2"><br></div>
<div class="col3"><br></div>
<div class="col4"><br></div>
<div class="col5"><br></div>
<br><br>
</div>
<p>The green is fine and also the other gradient colors once start/stop values are set</p>
```

For infos , this is a method that was called the "faux-columns" when almost only float was avalaible .https://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns/